# Publish Metrics to Different Port in Prometheus

Tags: node.js, prometheus

I am using express in my Node js App to run a server on 3000.I can publish metrics to Prometheus if scrape_configs:

```
# The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'referral'

    # metrics_path defaults to '/metrics'
    # scheme defaults to 'http'.

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:3000']
```

And in Node server side

```
const Prometheus = require('prom-client');
const app = express();
const metricsInterval = Prometheus.collectDefaultMetrics();
const test = new Prometheus.Counter({
  name: 'num_of_requests',
  help: 'Number of requests made',
  labelNames: ['method', 'route', 'code']
});

test.inc({ method: "GET", route: url, code: status });

app.get('/metrics', (req, res) => {
  res.set('Content-Type', Prometheus.register.contentType)
  res.end(Prometheus.register.metrics())
});
```

This is working fine.Now, what if I want to change the port Prometheus is listening to other than 3000.Is it feasible to do run express server on different port and publish metrics on a different port?

Comment: Did you get a solution to the above problem? if so, can you please share?

Comment: Check out [this example from the JS prom-client](https://github.com/siimon/prom-client/blob/master/example/cluster.js). Should be easy to adapt to expose basic metrics via `/metrics` as above, rather than aggregated metrics as in the example.